# Cannot access Instagram Celebrity users public posts using Instagram Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram-api

Why I am not able to read(access) the posts from instagram celebrity users just like I am able to get it from Facebook users using the newly released Graph API for instagram?

I suspect that there are restrictions to read public posts of celebrity(verified users) on Instagram due to Cambridge Analytica User Data Abuse. Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You are right, It's due to cambridge analytica side effects.
This one more sudden change from Insatagram,

User search endpoints are deprecated immediately, with some other endpoints. It's effective from 4th April.

User Search:

```
GET /users/{user-id}

GET /users/{user-id}/media/recent

GET /users/self/media/liked

GET /users/search
```

https://www.instagram.com/developer/changelog/

https://newsroom.fb.com/news/2018/04/restricting-data-access/

This is the reason you cannot access celebrity profile, Not only celebrity, you cannot access any user details.

Comment: Can you please delete your answer I am getting negative marks and also I am not able to delete the question since you have answered it?